# How to get reliable results when measuring computation time of a function with python?

Tags: python, performance, time

I wrote some function in python and want to measure its computation time for different inputs. I noticed that even when using the same input multiple times, each time the measured time will be different, I assume that's because the state of the PC might be different each time (in regards to used memory etc.) or something of the sort? Anyway, is there a way to eliminate this random factor so that the measurement becomes deterministic and reliable?

I am using the [time library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) and the perf_counter_ns function to measure the time.

Comment: Use [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html)

Comment: also keep in mind that in any modern multi-processing OS, it's impossible to get the same results for a process execution reliably. Too many things might be different. The best you can do is run the computation lots of times and get the average. And that's what timeit does.

Answer (score 1):

The `timeit` module may be what you're looking for. Here's official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html